# Correlation between two categorical variables

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data

I have **two categorical variable** and I would like to check if this two variables have correlation.

Is the right option to use `spearman rho coefficient correlation`?

The levels for one are 4 and for the other variable are 5.

I used Spearman's correlation coefficient rho with p-value < 0.05 to accept the null hypothesis which shows the correlation. Is it the right option?

Example of data

```
va1 var2
0    2
1    1
2    3
2    1
0    2
1    3
```

Comment: is one numeric and the other categorical ? or they are both categorical ?

Comment: I think this post extensively answers your question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893/how-to-get-correlation-between-two-categorical-variable-and-a-categorical-variab

Comment: Are they nominal or ordinal? How many levels does each have?

Comment: @PeterFlom They are ordinal. Nominal are only (0 or 1 levels). The levels for one are 4 and for the other variable are 5.

Comment: Please add that information to the question itself.

Comment: @PeterFlom I made the update. However, the question is closed. I guess I can't receive an answer

Comment: @PeterFlom thank you. I added an example of data

Comment: @PeterFlom is the right option to use chi-squared test?

Comment: What do you mean by "nominal is only 0 or 1 level"?

Comment: @MichaelM please take a look at the example data structure